# VC++ and MFC Applications

Tags: mfc

Can anyone suggest the links for implementing the CUT Option as in the case of MS PAINT for selecting the particular portion of the image drawn and pasting the same.....!

Answer (score 1):

Try starting here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80db3kax(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Also, please accept answers on some of your earlier questions! Click on the checkmark under the number of votes to the left of the answer.